# how to set a background for a button with specific id in android?

Tags: android, button, background

I am generating `Buttons` programatically in my program. 
What I am trying to do is as follows.

I am generating 4 buttons each with `id` 0,1,2 and 3.

On clicking button with id 1 I want to change the background of the button with id=1 to red and the remaining other buttons will have the default grey color.

When I click button with id=2 I want the button with id=2 to change to red background and the button with id =1 to change to default grey color.

I want only the currently clicked button to be red i.e only one button remains red at a time. I tried to do the following but the previously clicked button also remains red. Can anyone tell me step by step what to do?

codes:

```
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
           {

          final Button tv1 = new Button(this);
            tv1.setId(i);
            tv1.setText(value);
            tv1.setTextSize(25);
            tv1.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(tv1));
            }

    private OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button tv1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


      Log.i("dynamiclly generated button click id",""+btn_id);
            String text = tv1.getText().toString();

            Log.e("text message", "" + text);
            tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.red));
            Toast.makeText(MenuItemsActivity.this,
                    "clicked" + v.getId() + "," + tv1.getId(), 1000).show();
            display_category(text);
            //btn_id=tv1.getId();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I think you should change like:

`onClick` of any `Button` you have to change first of all color of all button with `GRAY` and then change selected button `RED` for selected Button.

Comment: please can you explain in detail?

Comment: have you check my ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for you change button color

```
 return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i=buttonStartID;i<buttonMaxID;i++){
                Button btn = (Button) findViewById(i);
                btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.grey));
            }

            Log.i("dynamiclly generated button click id", "" + btn_id);
            String text = tv1.getText().toString();

            Log.e("text message", "" + text);
            tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.red));
            Toast.makeText(MenuItemsActivity.this,
                    "clicked" + v.getId() + "," + tv1.getId(), 1000).show();
            display_category(text);
            // btn_id=tv1.getId();
        }
    };
```

Comment: That is what i have said.

Answer (score 0):

How about using switch case:

```
switch(btn_id){

case 1:
     tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.red));
     break;

case 2:
     tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.blue));
     break;
.
.
.

case n:
     tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.green));
     break;

default:
     tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.grey));
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnrButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout lnrButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lnrButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrButton);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            Button button = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = 10;
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setId(i);
            button.setText("Button" + (i + 1));
            button.setTextSize(25);
            button.setTag(i);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int i=0;i<lnrButton.getChildCount();i++){
                        if(i==(Integer)v.getTag()){
                            ((Button)lnrButton.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }else{
                            ((Button)lnrButton.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            lnrButton.addView(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button tv1 = new Button(this);
tv1.setId(i);
tv1.setText(value);
tv1.setTextSize(25);
tv1.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
Button tv2 = new Button(this);
tv2.setId(i);
tv2.setText(value);
tv2.setTextSize(25);
tv2.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
Button tv3 = new Button(this);
tv3.setId(i);
tv3.setText(value);
tv3.setTextSize(25);
tv3.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
Button tv4 = new Button(this);
tv4.setId(i);
tv4.setText(value);
tv4.setTextSize(25);
tv4.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
resetBG():
(Button) findViewById(v.getID())setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.red));
}
private void reset(){
  tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(SET_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE);
  tv2.setBackgroundDrawable(SET_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE);
  tv3.setBackgroundDrawable(SET_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE);
  tv4.setBackgroundDrawable(SET_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE);
}
```